# Python socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: sockets, python-2.7

I'm trying to use sockets with python, but I keep on getting this error message:

```
import socket
>>> s = socket.socket( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM )
>>> s.connect(('localhost', 8000))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stdin", line 1, in module
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

config in /etc/hosts is :

```
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

System is ubuntu 12.04 , no firewall configured.
Tried to change port number , but no luck; it works only with domains different from
 "localhost". Does someone knows why it happens?

Comment: Is anything listening on that port on your machine?

Comment: No, nothing. Could that be a firewall issue or a privileges one? .I had the same problem on win7 , so i configured the win firewall to allow python to connect to localhost , and then it worked ..

Comment: If nothing is listening, you can't connect.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
s = socket.socket( socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_STREAM )
s.connect(('::1', 8000))
```

you seem to have only ipv6 enabled.

Comment: sorry.. after a double check my /etc/hosts is like this   127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 michele-System-Product-Name

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters