# Trouble setting up python mapreduce - mincemeat.py

Tags: python, mapreduce, mincemeat

I am trying to setup `mincemeat.py` on my system and am installing from source into a prefix folder. I use virtualenv and have python installed from source into a prefix directory. I am trying to install mincemeat.py to the same prefix directory.

I downloaded mincemeat-0.1.2.tar.gz and unzipped it. It contains mincemeat.py, setup.py, and the build. I tried to install by using

```
python setup.py install -prefix="/nlu/users/ind/"
```

I also have example.py in the same folder mincemeat-0.1.2. I tried to start the client by giving

```
python mincemeat.py -p changeme localhost
```

but it cannot start the client. The error is:

```
error: uncaptured python exception, closing channel <__main__.Client at 0x1b9d5a8> 
(<class 'socket.error'>:[Errno 111] Connection refused 
 [/nlu/users/ind/lib/python2.7/asyncore.py|read|83] 
 [/nlu/users/ind/lib/python2.7/asyncore.py|handle_read_event|441] 
 [/nlu/users/ind/python2.7/asyncore.py|handle_connect_event|449])
```

How do I check if my mincemeat installation is right? Also, where should I place my example.py? Please suggest how to get this working.

Comment: It sounds like you may be trying to start a client when the server isn't running?  It's hard to tell, though.  Can you provide more detail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run BOTH server and client. 

Commands to be executed in separated consoles:
Console 1 (first): python example.py
Console 2 (later): python mincemeat.py -p changeme localhost

Example of steps: https://github.com/michaelfairley/mincemeatpy#example

Answer (score 3):

mincemeat.py doesn't need to be set up or installed. If you have python 2.7 installed (which you do based on the error message) you should be able to run

```
python mincemeat.py -p changeme localhost
```

from the directory that has mincemeat.py in. I don't think the problem is how you installed mincemeat but some odd set up on your machine.

Do you only have IPV6 as in this post here: [Python socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused on ubuntu 12.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10463965/python-socket-error-errno-111-connection-refused-on-ubuntu-12-04) ?

Oh and you can put example.py in the same folder as mincemeat.py.